# Impossible to code sign apps in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode

Here's yet another Xcode 9 Provisioning Problem Question.

I can't put my app on my phone using the iOS Developer Certificate.

I can't delete the certificate. Under `Manage Certificates...` the Revoke Certificate button is greyed out. Sometimes it says `Not in Keychain` next to the license.

This means that I also can't create a new one, Xcode just complains `You already have a current iOS Developer certificate or a pending certificate request.`

Using `Automatically manage signing` fails with "Automatic signing failed" and "Signing certificate is invalid." There is no revoke option.

Trying to manually import the certificate from the `~\Library\MobileDevices\Provisioning Profiles` folder doesn't work either. It says that there is `No signing certificate "iOS Development" found` and `Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: (app name)" is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed profile.`

`Download Profiles Manually...` doesn't work either. Nothing changes.

In `Build Settings,` I tried setting the `Code Signing Identity` settings to "Don't Code Sign." I also tried setting `Provisioning Profiles` to None. I still can't send the app to my phone.

Deleting the files in the `Provisioning Profiles` folder doesn't do anything.

There is nothing in `Window > Organizer.`

Signing out of and back into my account in Xcode doesn't fix anything.

Creating a completely new project results in the same problem.

I tried rebooting too.

Since the certificate is Xcode-managed, it wouldn't be in my Developer Account. Furthermore, I use a free account, so I wouldn't be able to remove the certificate from there anyway.

The question: How do I revoke my old certificate that isn't in the Keychain and create a new one to send apps to my phone?

I used to be able to send apps to devices, but it just stopped working.

Comment: Does this issue happen with all apps, or only a specific one? What happens when you create a new app from a template?

Comment: This happens with both apps that I tried. Creating a game with the "Game" template has the same problem.